# UNIQUE constraint failed when trying to use ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
       return  self.name

class MenuSection(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(
        Restaurant,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
    food_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.food_type + " - " + self.restaurant.name


class MenuItem(models.Model):
    MenuSection = models.ForeignKey(
       MenuSection,
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
    food_item = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.food_item + " - " + self.restaurant.name
```

When I try to migrate these changes I get the error: "
`no such column: core_menuitem.id`" at the command line and when I try and access /admin it says:
"`no such column: core_menuitem.id`". Does anyone know what the issue is? Thanks in advance

Comment: `MenuSection = models.ForeignKey( MenuSection, #...)`You are using model name MenuSection. Make a change there. Add something like `menusection = model.#..`

Answer (score 0):

Please rename your MenuSection field in MenyItem as it's same as `Foreign key` class, moreover it's bad practice to name fields in CamelCase, name it with underscore as following:

```
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    menu_section = models.ForeignKey( # <- This field name
       MenuSection,
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    food_item = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And try running migrations with:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```